# Batch File to find duplicate files and delete the dupes

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, duplicates

I have a bit of code that is very close to what I need, but I can't quite figure out the delete part.  This needs to be created as code for .bat file.

I want to do the following:

1. Check a folder for its files.
2. Check a second folder and if the second folder has any files with the same fileNAME as the original folder, delete it from the second folder (only).
3. Check a third folder and if the third folder has the same fileNAME as the original folder, delete it from the third folder (only).

This works perfectly to copy any duplicate files to a new directory:

```
for %%F in ("E:\Temp only\dupe test\Holding Area\**") do (
    if exist "E:\Temp only\dupe test\Stock Folder\%%~nxF" copy "%%~fF" "E:\Temp only\dupe test\Destination\%%~nxF"
    if exist "E:\Temp only\dupe test\Special\%%~nxF" copy "%%~fF" "E:\Temp only\dupe test\Destination\%%~nxF"
)
```

So instead of "copy" to a new folder, I need to delete the duplicate file from the folder that the dupe exists in.  The first folder is the "Original" to check against, and files should never be deleted from there.

Please help if you can.  And thanks so much!

Comment: and you just don't change `COPY` with `DEL` ?

Comment: no, it deletes from the original folder.

Comment: `copy "%%~fF" "E:\Temp only\dupe test\Destination\%%~nxF"` to `del "E:\Temp only\dupe test\Destination\%%~nxF"`

Comment: and `copy "%%~fF" "E:\Temp only\dupe test\Destination\%%~nxF"` to `del "E:\Temp only\dupe test\Destination\%%~nxF"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off 

setlocal 

set "source_folder=E:\Temp only\dupe test\Holding Area" 
set "folder2=E:\Temp only\dupe test\Stock Folder" 
set "folder1=E:\Temp only\dupe test\Special" 

set "log_file=.\log.txt" 

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%F in ("%source_folder%\*") do ( 

    if exist "%folder2%\%%~nxF" ( 
        echo deleting "%folder2%\%%~nxF"  at !date! !time!
        del /q /f "%folder2%\%%~nxF" 
        if exist "%folder2%\%%~nxF" echo deleting failed 

    )>> "%log_file%" 

    if exist "%folder1%\%%~nxF" ( 
        echo deleting "%folder1%\%%~nxF" at !date! !time! 
        del /q /f "%folder1%\%%~nxF" 
        if exist "%folder1%\%%~nxF" echo deleting failed 
    )>> "%log_file%" 
) 
endlocal
endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured this out.  This seems to work anyway.  Let me know if you see any issues with this that I may be overlooking.

```
for %%F in ("E:\Temp only\dupe test\Holding Area\**") do (
if exist "E:\Temp only\dupe test\Stock Folder\%%~nxF" del "E:\Temp only\dupe test\Stock Folder\%%~nxF" 
if exist "E:\Temp only\dupe test\Special\%%~nxF" del "E:\Temp only\dupe test\Special\%%~nxF" 
)
```

Comment: you can use `DEL /Q /F "file"` to make the delete command more ..hmm... powerful .

Comment: Is there anyway to log what was done into a log file?

Comment: thanks! what do those things do?  and what do you mean more "powerful"?

Comment: set `> log.txt` after the last bracket.

Comment: like this?
for %%F in ("E:\Temp only\dupe test\Holding Area\**") do (
    if exist "E:\Temp only\dupe test\Stock Folder\%%~nxF" del "E:\Temp only\dupe test\Stock Folder\%%~nxF" 
    if exist "E:\Temp only\dupe test\Special\%%~nxF" del "E:\Temp only\dupe test\Special\%%~nxF" 
) > log.txt

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61705/discussion-between-tim-s-and-npocmaka).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation where I need to delete a tif file when a PDF of the same name is available. here is a 5 line batch file code.

```
rem A simpler solution to traverse sub-folders with a root folder provided and remove files with the same name but different extension.

@echo on 
for /R %%I in (*.tif) do ( 
@echo checking 
if exist %%~dI%%~pI%%~nI.PDF del %%I ) 
pause
```

Put this code in a batch file and supply the root-folder. The batch process will look at the all the files and sub-folders and delete all tif files.